# C#: Get the Type that the parameter belongs to

Tags: c#

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    protected void SomeMethod<T>(String paramName, ref T myParam, T val)
    {
        //Get the Type that myParam belongs to...
        //(Which happens to be Car or Plane in this instance)
        Type t = typeof(...);
    }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    private String _model;
    public String Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { SomeMethod<String>("Model", ref _model, value); }
    }
}

public class Plane: Vehicle
{
    private Int32 _engines;
    public In32 Engines
    {
        get { return _engines; }
        set { SomeMethod<Int32>("Engines", ref _engines, value); }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do what I'm looking for... that is, get t be typeof(Car) or typeof(Plane) using the referenced parameter myParam somehow?

Oh, and I would like to avoid having to pass in a 'this' instance to SomeMethod or adding another Generic constraint parameter if I can.

Comment: Any chance you are going to raise the PropertyChanged event? Can you tell us why you need the Type? You might not need it.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you'd need to `GetType()`, unless you're doing a type-test. With very high probability, I bet there's a way to re-write whatever you're doing without a type test at all.

Comment: @Juliet: I wanted to get the type just to use it with `Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Type: {0}, Property: {1}", GetType(), paramName));`.

I didn't realize that GetType get's the actual type. For whatever reason I thought it would just return the base type, but it doesn't... in fact I didn't even need the `Type t = typeof(...)`, but apparantly `this.GetType()` was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass in `this` - it's already an instance method.

Just use:

```
Type t = this.GetType();
```

That will give the *actual* type of vehicle, not `Vehicle`.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems like he wants `typeof(T)`.

Comment: That actually makes sense. So am I to assume if I kept inheriting down `Honda : Car` ... `HondaAccord : Honda` that it'll have `HondaAccord` or `Honda` as the 'this' ?

Comment: @Gabe, no, he definitely wants `this.GetType();` See his example, he wants `typeof(Car)` and `typeof(Engine)`. In his generic methods, T is `String` and `Int32`. `Type t` and `T` are two different concerns.

Comment: No... T is just used so I could do `T myParam, T val` instead of `Object myParam, Object val` and then having to cast.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `GetType()` which will operate on the current instance. It's a little misleading because the code lives in the base class, but it will correctly get the inherited class type for you at runtime.

```
Type t = this.GetType(); 
/*or equivlently*/
Type t = GetType();
```

On a side note you don't have to pass the type into `SomeMethod` it will be infered for you by the compiler.

```
public class Car : Vehicle 
{ 
    private String _model; 
    public String Model 
    { 
        get { return _model; } 
        set { SomeMethod("Model", ref _model, value); } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The type T I pass is for the _model and value, so I don't have to cast them from Object to their types.

Comment: @myermain Correct, I would keep the function generic, but I'm saying you don't have to specify the generic when calling the method. The compiler is smart enough to add the generic. If you called `SomeMethod("Model", ref _model, value )` the compiler would actually call `SomeMethod<String>( "Model", re model, value )`. It picks up the type from the parameters. It saves you a step and there's one less thing to modify if the type of the parameter changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make `SomeMethod` non-generic and then `Type t = this.GetType()`.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of expanding on this base method. I just want to expand on it, not copy/paste it into all the classes using the base class.

Comment: Not downvoting, but the second part of your answer does not require the first part. `SomeMethod` is not generic based on the type of the object, but rather the type of a parameter.